# Correct touch location after zooming and panning a pdf drawn in CATiledLayer on top of the UIScrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, catiledlayer, vfr-reader

I am working on Atlas App in which I am displaying map which I can zoom and pan using pdf file. I am using **vfr reader** for this purpose and it is working fine. I want to detect the touch location so that I can get the correct state selected. I am getting the correct coordinate when view is not zoomed and panned using the code below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:theScrollView];
}
```

But,when I zoom it out and pan it,the touch location changes and I am not getting the correct state selected. How will I get the correct selected state?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On debugging **vfr** reader classes I found that I can get the correct exact location of touch in **ReaderContentPage** class. This class gives the correct touch location after zooming also. You can get the point in processingSingleTap method as below:

```
- (id)processSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];
}
```

**CGPoint point** gives the correct touch location. And then use the delegate method to get the correct coordinates in the required class.